# Must I create an activity for each page of my book reader app in android

Tags: android

I am creating an app in android which loads text(HTML) and images, this app is a book. I have a listview with a search box on top. On selecting an item, (which is simply a page) the app loads it for the user to read. I am stuck in that I have to created an activity for each page. I wanted to reuse one activity which I named DisplayActity , this activity contains a webview to display my content. I am somehow still an android newbie
Must I do this in as many pages as I have and also create as many activities as the number of my book pages?

Comment: Just need one activity as you say `DisplayActity` and display content as you want..

Answer (score 1):

No. When the user elects to switch pages, just update the content in your existing `DisplayActivity`. For example, if `DisplayActivity` shows the content via a `WebView`, update the `WebView` for the newly-selected page.

Comment: Oh yeah, I have figured out how to implement one activity to use as my display, however, I have run into trouble: